# How to connect to spring boot logs inside docker container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker

I have spring boot java application running inside docker container at remote server. When I started it with docker-compose up command, I could see logs of my application. Now I want to see it again, but don't understand how to connect to my application console again.

I have connected to docker container terminal via "docker exec -it bash" command. But have no idea what to do next. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Find the id of the running container by showing all containers using `docker ps`, and display logs of your application with `docker logs <container_id>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I started it with docker-compose up command

Assuming the contiainer is still running, you would use `docker-compose logs`, if not then you need to re-run `up`.